# Selectpicker add option in optgroup

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I want to add an option in an `optgroup` using jQuery. I am using bootstrap selectpicker. The following is my code:

```js
var groupOption = "<option value='123'>123</option>";
$("#selectpickerdemo").append(groupOption).selectpicker('refresh');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" multiple name="selectpickerdemo" id="selectpickerdemo">
  <optgroup label="Label 1">
    <option value='abc'>ABC</option>
    <option value='abcd'>ABCD</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Label 2">
    <option value='abc'>ABC</option>
    <option value='abcd'>ABCD</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: You simply need to select the `optgroup` element before calling `append()`, not the `select` as you currently do.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I have tried. I gave id to each optgroup and try to add option using that id, but it was not working

Answer (score 1):

Please use `id` attribute (or others like `class`, etc).
e.g.

```
...
<optgroup label="Label 1" id="label1">
    <option value='abc'>ABC</option>
    <option value='abcd'>ABCD</option>
</optgroup>
...

var opt_label1 = $("#label1" );
$("<option>").text('option text').val('option value').appendTo(opt_label1);
```

For more details, please refer to this example.
http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/493qa/

Comment: I want to add under particular optgroup. e.g Under Label 1 or Label 2

Comment: Using `id` or `class` attributes, get an jQuery Object of `optgroup` from it.
And use `appendTo` method to add `option` to the jQuery Object.

Comment: I tried, but bootstrap convert optgroup and option into ul li format

Comment: I see, probably, you're using bootstrap template. Can you please let me know your bootstrap version?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.6

Answer (score 0):

Select the `<optgroup` based on `id` or `label` like a normal selector.

**Relevant code:**

```
$("#selectpickerdemo optgroup#label1").append(groupOption).selectpicker('refresh');
```

If you have a label and no ID, use it the following way:

```
$("#selectpickerdemo optgroup[label='Label 1']").append(groupOption).selectpicker('refresh');
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
var groupOption = "<option value='123'>123</option>";
$("#selectpickerdemo optgroup#label1").append(groupOption).selectpicker('refresh');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker" multiple name="selectpickerdemo" id="selectpickerdemo">
  <optgroup label="Label 1" id="label1">
    <option value='abc'>ABC</option>
    <option value='abcd'>ABCD</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Label 2" id="label2">
    <option value='abc'>ABC</option>
    <option value='abcd'>ABCD</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.