# How to add option to select list in jQuery whit "selectpicker" class?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have 2 select list and I want add option to both  select lists in `jQuery`. I add option  with bellow code in `jQuery` but this work just on list1 and not work on  list2 with `id=mySelect2` because list2 have class.

```
$("#mySelect1").append(new Option("option text", "value"));
$("#mySelect2").append(new Option("option text", "value"));
```

MY  Jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/magi2109/3p6qm0yu/1/).

List1:

```
<select id='mySelect1'     >
<option value="4444">4444</option>
<option value="Elite1">Elite1</option>
<option value="Elite">Elite</option>
</select>
```

---

List2:

```
<select id='mySelect2'   data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith" class="selectpicker"  >

<option value="4444">4444</option>
<option value="Elite1">Elite1</option>
<option value="Elite">Elite</option>

</select>
```

How can I add option  to list2?

I use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49981693/12274302) but not work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **refresh** method to add (or, even remove) options. You may do something like this:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#mySelect2').selectpicker();
});

$('#addButton').click(function(){
    let valuetoadd = prompt('What to add?');
  $('#mySelect2,#mySelect1').append(`<option value="${valuetoadd}">${valuetoadd}</option>`);
  $('#mySelect2').selectpicker('refresh');
})
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

 
    


<select id='mySelect1'     >
<option value="4444">4444</option>
<option value="Fedex">Fedex</option>
<option value="Elite">Elite</option>
</select>

<hr>


<select id='mySelect2'   data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith"  >

<option value="4444">4444</option>
<option value="Fedex">Fedex</option>
<option value="Elite">Elite</option>

</select>

<button id="addButton">
Add New Value
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call the `render` method on the `selectpicker` element after adding the new option

```
$("#mySelect1").append(new Option("option text", "value"));
$("#mySelect2").append(new Option("option text", "value"));
$("#mySelect2").selectpicker('render')
```

https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrender

Comment: thanks @Albab  and @Kinglish  we must use `$("#mySelect2").selectpicker('render')`   instead  `$("#mySelect2").selectpicker('render')`